# Do companions use poisons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I give a few poisons for my companions to carry, will they use them in battle?

And if the answer is yes - is there a way to control when they're used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they will not use poison. However, you could try poisoning a weapon and giving it to your companion if you need it in a tougher fight. Otherwise, you're stuck with the normal, unpoisoned weapon your companion uses.

Answer (score -3):

I have a Janessa follower. Not only that she uses healing potions on her self, she also used the invibility potion and a paralize poison in battle. I think the 'class' of your follower is relavent.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you got 3 down votes because we don't share what we have encountered in Arqade unless it goes with an answer. if you do want to share something like that, comment about it.